# Asp.Net Menu Highlighting

Tags: menu, master-pages, asp.net-3.5

I try to figure out what's the best strategy to manage a menu in Asp.Net and highlight the "active" menu-item.

That's have to be done in the MasterPage but it's the Page that know what menu-item to highlight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found that implementing a custom SQL Site Map Provider combined with impementing a fully custom menu component, one just need to render the menu html depending on the application/design etc. For intance I have just recently implemented the jQuery Superfish Menu using our Menu component.

jQuery is great for searching and selecting particular classes/elements and applying styles/classes as required.

Some Helpful URLS:

http://users.tpg.com.au/j_birch/plugins/superfish/

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163657.aspx

http://dotnetslackers.com/VB_NET/re-17169_Rendering_a_databound_UL_menu.aspx

HTH